# numpy digitize with datetime64

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, datetime64

I can't seem to get numpy.digitize to work with datetime64:

```
date_bins = np.array([np.datetime64(datetime.datetime(2014, n, 1), 's') for n in range(1,13)])
np.digitize(date_bins, date_bins)
```

It gives the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('<M8[s]') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 8):

get an `i8` view of `datetime` values:

```
>>> date_bins_i8 = date_bins.view('i8')
>>> np.digitize(date_bins_i8, date_bins_i8)
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12])
```

`i8` is 64-bit integer data type and [`view`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) constructs a view of the array's memory.